# Set twig path function to form's action using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, path, action, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.3.4 and of course Twig.

Now, I'm trying to set twig's function path() to a form's action, the problem is... well that I can't.

when I run this:

```
$('#prof_create').prop('action',"{{ path('profesor_create') }}");
```

what I'm aiming for is this result:

```
<form id="prof_create" class="form-horizontal sf_admin_form_area" 
action="/SVN/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/admin/profesor/create" method="post" 
{{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

being {{ path('profesor_create') }} -> /SVN/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/admin/profesor/create

the javascript file shows no error nor warning but it's really not working because when I try to submit the form:
Error

No route found for "POST /admin/profesor/%7B%7B%20path(%27profesor_create%27)%20%7D%7D"

which means it did not "transform"

```
{{ path('profesor_create') }}
```

into

```
/SVN/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/admin/profesor/create
```

what I want NOT to do is to write down the entire address in the js function, is there a way to get this done?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Twig and its Variables are rendered and processed before the actual HTML output is shown in your browser.

Therefore in that case {{ path('profesor_create') }} is just another string, which is not handled by the Twig Engine since it has run already and generated the output.

Either render your route before hand and set it where you need it, or use a javascript routing bundle like https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle to render your route in JS to work with it.

Comment: Honestly I had never heard of that bundle, I will take a look into it in case I need it in the future. Regarding my problem I solved it with an ajax request in the onclick() event of the form's submit button. Check it out and thanks anyway, too bad still don't have 15 rep otherwise I would thumb you up.

Comment: sorry I mixed two problems up, it wasn't with ajax, it was a simple jquery function, all it needed was to be implemented in the html.twig file instead of in the .js so the twig variable would be properly rendered

Comment: You solved by exactlay following what I told you.
You put the route into the twig, placed your javascript directly there and therefore you made sure the route was rendered by twig..

Answer (score 0):

```
{# ../some.html.twig #}
<form id="prof_create" class="form-horizontal 
sf_admin_form_area" action="{{ path('profesorext_create') }}" 
      method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button onclick="before_submit_action()" id="submit_prof"  class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i> {{'Guardar' | trans}}</button>

        <a class="btn" href="{{ path('profesorext') }}">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> {{'Cancelar' | trans }}</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function before_submit_action() {
    if(<condition_met>)
        $('#prof_create').attr('action',{{ path('profesor_create') }});
    else
        $('#prof_create').attr('action',{{ path('profesorext_create') }});
}
</script>
```